# Will HTML5 in any way enable a better charting with ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: charts

I am in the process developing a view page with charts, will HTML5 enhance the view, means are there any chart related features in HTML5. I am using ASP.Net MVC2 and also would like to have  charts with clickable bars or pie slices.

If there can be any better option, do let me know of..

Answer (score 0):

There are many javacript libraries to help with this sort of thing - it is not really a function of HTML5. You will generally set up some sort of structure to feed into the library, it render a table which the library will turn into a graph.

Personally I have used [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/)

Comment: Does the plugin that you suggest support varying the intervals for the axis (x or y) for all numeric and datetime datatypes.

Comment: You just give it the data and config and it will pretty much do what you want. There are other libraries...that just happens to the be one I use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) as well.

jqChart is a pure HTML5 Chart for jQuery and ASP.NET MVC.